# Unable to access WebUI when Trino is secured behind a load balancer and LDAP authentication is enabled

Tags: ldap, load-balancing, trino

I am setting up a development server for Trino using Trino's docker image. I need to integrate Trino to LDAP so we decided to secure Trino behind a load balancer (see [here](https://trino.io/docs/current/security/tls.html)) but after enabling password authentication, we see the following when we access Trino (https://trino_domain) WebUI:
[image]

My config.properties are as follows:

[image]

By right I should be prompted with the usual login screen with the password field enabled. There is no errors in the logs. The only warning I could find is

[image]

I could not find anything on google on this so I am not sure what is missing/wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior when attempting to connect via http when the coordinator is configured for https.

This video might help you configure Trino with a load balancer and LDAP:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KiMyRc3PSh0

Comment: Hei, thanks for the video. I look through the video and I am starting to think that maybe the load balancer is not set correctly. This is because if I disabled password authentication and access trino via https, i am able to see the wed ui page. However, once i enter a username and clicked login, i am forwarded back to http.

Comment: I would advise setting up load balancer only after Trino cluster is up and running correctly. Try removing the load balancer from the equation for now. If my answer above helped resolve "Web Interface Disabled" error, please apply green check mark. Thank you!

Comment: The appropriate headers not set in the load balencer.

Comment: After spending days, got this - https://docs.starburst.io/latest/admin-topics/security